# How to transform NSData back into the original file?

Tags: cocoa, core-data

I am creating a custom NSValueTransformer subclass to save a file as a Transformable attribute in Core Data. I am using `[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:value];` to transform one way, but how do I get the file back?

This is an arbitrary file, so how can I determine what kind it is so I can display the images or open it with a proper application?

Thanks

Chet

Comment: I was just trying to break down the problem into smaller parts...

Comment: Did you see my updated answer to your earlier question? I suggested using a binary attribute rather than a transformable.  Also included how to get and set the attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Save the URL and/or mime type as we'll so you can examine it (the extension) later to decide what to do.

Comment: It was determined that for the sake of syncing with iOS database, it would be better save the file data. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21128593/how-to-upload-and-store-files-in-cocoa-with-core-data

Comment: then again, i don't really know what I'm doing here or what is the best way

Comment: That is a good way. You don't want to store large amounts of arbitrary data blobs in core data really.